# Floating text to the right affecting the container's width (no constant sizes)

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment

Suppose I have the following UI:

```
<div>
    <span class="normal">text</span>
    <span class="pull-right">blah</span>
</div>
```

and style:

```
.pull-right {
    float: right;
    /* What should I put here to make "blah" appear on the same line as text? */
}
div {
    float: left; /* for wrapping the contents */
    border: 1px solid green; /* to help see the bounds */
}
.normal {
    border: 1px solid blue; /* to help see the bounds */
}
```

**Actual result**: When displayed in a browser (Chrome in my case) the `blah` is displayed below and to the right of `text` and the `div` is almost as wide as the two texts.

That's almost what I want.

**Expected result**: I want `blah` to be displayed to the right of `text` in the same line and the `div` (green box) to have the width of `text` and `blah`'s width added together (without specifying any specific width values.

Here's a fiddle with the above minimal example and the original context where I have the same problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/TWiStErRob/5TruW/

**How should I style `blah` to make it work as expected?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the floated element before the text element.

If you think about it, the HTML processes the elements in order. So it writes the text span and then it writes the floated span. There is no way for it to move them the way you want. Float elements must come before the elements wrapping them.

Comment: Woah, magic :) I knew this a few years ago, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Just make it `display: inline;`  like so:

```
.pull-right {
    display: inline;
}
```

Actually, in fact, you don't have to put anything at all if you are applying this class to a `<span>` element because `<span>` will default to `inline` anyway. just remove the `float: right;`

Here's the updated jsfiddle as example:  http://jsfiddle.net/5TruW/6/

Comment: But I want it right aligned (sticking to the right border of the container), sorry I may have missed it in the description.

Comment: oh ok, I see. In that case, you would pretty much have to specify a width for `text` and `blah`'s parent container, and then float `text` left and float `blah` right.  Or the other option is to apply margin between `text` and `blah` to space them apart from each other. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you effort! What you described would be a solution, but it includes "specify a width", which I want to avoid at all costs. See the accepted answer; it's a nice, no-hacky solution.